# Building a dashboard UI with 20+ charts in React; should each chart component manage it's own data request?

Tags: reactjs, axios, xmlhttprequest, dashboard

I'm building a dashboard UI that will contain 20+ charts in React.

I've got an API that returns the data for each chart, and using Axios to make the requests from the React components to the API.

I have a few obvious options:

1. Have each chart component, using Axios, manage it's own request to the API for data
2. Have a central controller manage/sequence each request to the API for data, and then pass the response to each chart component
3. Modify the API so that it expects a single request, and returns a large response containing all the data for all of the charts

#1 feels the most flexible and modular, but I don't understand well how the browser handles a large number of simultaneous requests. Do modern browsers do a good job of sequencing multiple requests and handling a long queue, or is this approach likely to cause difficult-to-debug errors in my React code?

#3 seems like it could be fast and efficient, minimizing the number of calls, but now the API is tightly coupled to the UI; it feels like this could be difficult to maintain. (E.g., any time I add or change a chart in the UI, the API needs to be changed as well.)

#2 seems like a good balance, but if modern browsers are better suited to managing/queueing a large number of requests, should I be reinventing the wheel writing my own queue manager?

Are their established best practices/design patterns that apply here? Are the other considerations I haven't thought of?

I've actually tried option #1, and it seems to work OK, but this feels like it might be the kind of thing that, in practice, generates lots of errors (e.g., a queue of requests start failing) that could be difficult to debug, or creates a lot of unnecessary load on my API.

Hopefully this isn't too open-ended or opinion-based.

Comment: Use react query. Simple.